# C++ Pointer to a member function of any class with matching function signatures

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

How do I assign references of non-static member functions, with identical signatures, but from different classes, to a function pointer with a matching signature?

I can do this with the aid of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) from the C++ std library. I also do this all the time with regular C functions and no help from the std library. I am writing firmware and code-space is limited. If helpers from the C++ std library can do it, surely it must be possible to do it manually using purely C/C++ language constructs (pre C++11 preferred).

Example code demonstrating my intention:

```
class A {
public:
    void ping_event_handler();
};

class B {
public:
    void ping_event_handler();
};

void A::ping_event_handler_A() {
    // Handle ping event in A...
}

void B::ping_event_handler_B() {
    // Handle ping event in B...
}

void ping_event_handler_C() {
    // Handle ping event in normal function...
}

int main() {

    // Ping event "pointer to a function that takes no arguments"
    void (*ping_event)();

    A a();
    B b();

    ping_event = a.ping_event_handler; // Attach class A's handler
    ping_event();                      // Trigger event

    ping_event = b.ping_event_handler; // Attach class B's handler
    ping_event();                      // Trigger event

    ping_event = ping_event_handler;   // Attach non-class handler
    ping_event();                      // Trigger event

}
```

Comment: For a start `A a();` is wrong. This is declaring a function `a`

Comment: `ping_event = a.ping_event_handler;` - How will the compiler know what value to give to `this`?

Comment: Consider either declaring these methods as static (if they don't need state of the object) or virtual (inherited from a common base class) and replace pointer to a function with a pointer to a base class. If you want to mix pointers to functions and pointers to methods, then you need some wrapper as std:function.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using function pointers. **void (*ping_event)();** is a pointer to the ordinary function and can not point to the class member function with it, that would be **void (A::*ping_event)(); for class A** and **void (B::*ping_event)(); for class B**. Making the member function static will work with your function pointer.

Comment: @bkVnet The base class thing would work, can't use std-lib, and don't want to be restricted to static functions. I'd hate to have to subclass just for my object to be able to handle events / signals. What seems to be the issue is that the compiler uses the Class type as part of the function signature, making it unable to be class independent. But if `std::function` can do it, then there must be a way that I can call the member function if I have a pointer with its signature and a pointer to one of it's objects. I feel casting will be involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way is to pass an `userData` with the function

```
void (*ping_event)(void* userData);
```

and save both the function and userData.
then in user side, casting the userData in it class and calling any method from it:

```
struct my_function
{
    my_function(void (*f)(void*), void* userData) : mF(f), mUserData(userData)
    {}

    void set(void (*f)(void*), void* userData)
    {
         mF = f;
         mUserData = userData;
    }

    void operator() () {
        mF(mUserData);
    }
    void (*mF)(void*);
    void* mUserData;
};
```

And at the call site:

```
template <typename C, void (C::*m)()>
void my_func_helper(void* userData)
{
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(userData);
    (c->*m)();
}


int main()
{
    A a;

    my_function f(&my_func_helper<A, &A::ping_event_handler>, &a);

    f();

    B b;

    f.set(&my_func_helper<B, &B::ping_event_handler>, &b);
    f();

    f.set(ping_event_handler_c, NULL);
    f();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc721dd338c838de)

Comment: Well done! Works perfect and with no std lib or subclassing. Could you possibly include what a function call would look like with an argument, for reference sake. Or is that not possible?

Comment: You have to change function pointer type, and change the function call:  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2458b90c6fad2f52)